# select columns on cat command

Tags: linux, bash, script, cat

I use a file as a little db table. The content is like this:

```
client1    john doe    engineer    cal
client2    jane doe    nurse       ny
client3    ali veli    doctor      ny
```

I want to find profession of client3. There is a "space" between name and surname, there is a "tab" between other columns. First column is unique so I can use this colums as private key.

I want to use a command for finding profession or state of a client by using a command like this:

```
grep -i client3 | "select 3rd column"
```

What can I use isntead of "select 3rd column"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"cut" command can be used for these situations. For this example we can use `grep -i client3 | cut -f 3` to find profession of client3. Same way we can see client2's name and surname at the same time by use `grep -i client2 | cut -f 2` Because there is only one "space" character between name and surname and `cut -f` command use "tabs" as a separator.